# How to prevent my inbuilt camera from turning off in low light

Tags: laptop, windows-registry, windows-11, webcam, asus-laptop

In low light my laptop camera (inbuilt) automatically switches to black and white, and then in even lower light it just switches off entirely until it detects sufficient light. Is there any way to disable this through the registry or something? I've looked online for a while and I've seen a few other people with similar issues.

My laptop model is VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X415DAP_M415DA, my camera is USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam, I'm on windows 11. If you need any further info let me know.

Comment: Did you install the latest drivers and make sure they don't provide some kind of interface to change it?

Comment: @Destroy666 - last revision of the UVC spec was 2012… I doubt much has changed since ;) To even guess any further, we need to at least know which version of the UVC protocol it supports. [though honestly, that behaviour sounds like the best way to get performance out of a really, really low spec camera.] Android have abandoned UVC support, Apple hasn't updated theirs in a decade. Windows info on UVC at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/stream/uvc-camera-implementation-guide [beyond my paygrade]

Comment: Would a third-party app, such as free *Webcam Settings Tool*,  https://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WebCam/Webcam-Settings-Tool.shtml, or an alternative, https://www.guru99.com/best-webcam-software-windows.html , give you more control?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The Webcam Settings tool seems to work! much appreciated